# Can I define synonyms for verbs in Luis bot framework?

Tags: botframework, entity, azure-language-understanding

In our company, we are building a `chatbot` using `Microsoft Luis Bot Framework`. For two of the `intent`'s, I don't know how I should annotate the examples.

I have a product called `ABC` and I need two different `intent`'s: `Access ABC` and `Use ABC`. That is, for each of these two intents, we have different answers.

Now, my questions is how can I define synonyms for verbs. Should I define verbs as `entities?` 
Our `utterance`s for the `intent` `Access ABC` would be like:

1) `How can I access ABC?`

2) `How can I reach ABC?`

Our `utterance`'s for the `intent` `Use ABC` would be like:

3) `How can I use ABC?`

4) `Is there any introduction to ABC?`

5) `I am new to ABC. Is there any usage guideline?`

The problem that I see is that if I don't tag the verbs for the first `intent`, how can the system distinguish between 1 (or 2) and 4?

Answer (score 0):

This is a big problem. In your utterences 1 and 2 for example, all you are teaching a model is that the verb access all the verb reach have no importance. this is because you are telling the models look at those two sentences both works regardless of what is a verb. This mean it will create quite a lot of confusions with your sentence number three. Training this model is still very empirical. We use QBox (disclaimer, I work for them). Having a couple of verbs uterences for each use case might work but you are going to have to try it. But be careful at your training examples. Try to vary as much as you can the word that play less importance. 
1- how can I access ABC
2- tell me how to reach ABC
3- I can't access ABC
4- I'm struggling to reach ABC

remember that you will need 10 to 15 examples minimum in order to reach a good level of performance. This depends of the number of intents you have in your model of course

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but sorry, I still haven't understood your meaning completely. Why do you say that "verb reach has no importanc?..the models look at those two sentences both works regardless of what is a verb". Why do you say that the verbs are not important? You mean to find the intents, the Luis models don't use the verbs at all? If it is so, why adding more instances as you have suggested will help?
I will of course add more instances, what I mentioned was just the problematic cases that came to my mind.

Comment: No sorry, I meant it is not important because your examples are too similar with just the verb changing, it is the equivalent to teach the model "look at those two sentences (1 and 2), they both right even when you change the verb.....so the conclusion is the verb is not important.....that is what the model will remember". So of course, for you the verb is the key, but because of your training data, your teaching the model the opposite. does that make more sense